# Play video in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I'm trying to play video in J2Me 
but It give me error

"The application can't be lunched . The application may have don in illegal operation.contact The application provider to resolve this issue 139"

So , what should I do To Fix this problem ??

```
package video;

import java.util.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.media.Manager;
import javax.microedition.media.Player;
import javax.microedition.media.PlayerListener;
import javax.microedition.media.control.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

/**
 * @author user
 */
public abstract class videoz extends MIDlet implements CommandListener, PlayerListener {

  private Display display;
  private List itemList;
  private Form form;

  private Command stopCommand;
  private Command pauseCommand;
  private Command startCommand;

  private Hashtable items;
  private Hashtable itemsInfo;

  private Player player;

  public videoz () {
    display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    // creates an item list to let you select multimedia files to play
    itemList = new List("Select an item to play", List.IMPLICIT);

    // stop, pause and restart commands
    stopCommand = new Command("Stop", Command.STOP, 1);
    pauseCommand = new Command("Pause", Command.ITEM, 1);
    startCommand = new Command("Start", Command.ITEM, 1);

    // a form to display when items are being played
    form = new Form("Playing media");

    // the form acts as the interface to stop and pause the media
    form.addCommand(stopCommand);
    form.addCommand(pauseCommand);
    form.setCommandListener(this);

    // create a hashtable of items
    items = new Hashtable();

    // and a hashtable to hold information about them
    itemsInfo = new Hashtable();

    // and populate both of them
    items.put("Promo Video from jar", "/res/Physics.3gp");
    itemsInfo.put("Promo Video from jar", "video/3gpp");
  }

    public void startApp() {
        // when MIDlet is started, use the item list to display elements
    for(Enumeration en = items.keys(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
    itemList.append((String)en.nextElement(), null);
     itemList.setCommandListener(this);

    // show the list when MIDlet is started
    display.setCurrent(itemList);
    }
    }
    public void pauseApp() {
        // pause the player
    try {
      if(player != null) player.stop();
    } catch(Exception e) {}
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
          if(player != null) player.close(); // close the player
    }

     public void commandAction(Command command, Displayable disp) {

    // generic command handler

    // if list is displayed, the user wants to play the item
    if(disp instanceof List) {
      List list = ((List)disp);

      String key = list.getString(list.getSelectedIndex());

      // try and play the selected file
      try {
        playMedia((String)items.get(key), key);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to play: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } else if(disp instanceof Form) {

      // if showing form, means the media is being played
      // and the user is trying to stop or pause the player
      try {

        if(command == stopCommand) { // if stopping the media play

          player.close(); // close the player
          display.setCurrent(itemList); // redisplay the list of media
          form.removeCommand(startCommand); // remove the start command
          form.addCommand(pauseCommand); // add the pause command

        } else if(command == pauseCommand) { // if pausing

          player.stop(); // pauses the media, note that it is called stop
          form.removeCommand(pauseCommand); // remove the pause command
          form.addCommand(startCommand); // add the start (restart) command
        } else if(command == startCommand) { // if restarting

          player.start(); // starts from where the last pause was called
          form.removeCommand(startCommand);
          form.addCommand(pauseCommand);
        }
      } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
      }
    }

  }

  /* Creates Player and plays media for the first time */
  private void playMedia(String locator, String key) throws Exception {


    // create the player
    // loading it as a resource and using information about it
    // from the itemsInfo hashtable
    player = Manager.createPlayer(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/Physics.3gp"), "video/3gpp");

    // a listener to handle player events like starting, closing etc
    player.addPlayerListener((PlayerListener) this);

    player.setLoopCount(-1); // play indefinitely
    player.prefetch(); // prefetch
    player.realize(); // realize

    player.start(); // and start
  }

  /* Handle player events */
  public void playerUpdate(Player player, String event, Object eventData) {

    // if the event is that the player has started, show the form
    // but only if the event data indicates that the event relates to newly
    // stated player, as the STARTED event is fired even if a player is
    // restarted. Note that eventData indicates the time at which the start
    // event is fired.
    if (event.equals(PlayerListener.STARTED) && new Long(0L).equals((Long)eventData))
        {
        // see if we can show a video control, depending on whether the media
        // is a video or not
        VideoControl vc = null;
        if((vc = (VideoControl)player.getControl("VideoControl")) != null)
                {
          Item videoDisp =
            (Item)vc.initDisplayMode(vc.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, null);
          form.append(videoDisp);
        }
        display.setCurrent(form);
    } 
        else if(event.equals(PlayerListener.CLOSED))
        {
      form.deleteAll(); // clears the form of any previous controls
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Alert;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Item;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.List;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.StringItem;
import javax.microedition.media.Manager;
import javax.microedition.media.Player;
import javax.microedition.media.control.GUIControl;
import javax.microedition.media.control.VideoControl;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;

public class DisplayVideoMIDlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {
  private List list = new List("Pick One", List.IMPLICIT);

  private Canvas canvas = new VideoCanvas();

  private Form form = new Form("Video Form", null);

  private StringItem descriptionItem = new StringItem("Desc: ", "Bad audio");

  Player player = null;

  private Command backCommand = new Command("Back", Command.ITEM, 1);

  private Command exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);

  private Alert alert = new Alert("Error");

  private Display display = null;

  private boolean error = false;

  public DisplayVideoMIDlet() {
    display = Display.getDisplay(this);

    canvas.addCommand(exitCommand);
    canvas.addCommand(backCommand);
    canvas.setCommandListener(this);

    form.append(descriptionItem);
    form.addCommand(exitCommand);
    form.addCommand(backCommand);
    form.setCommandListener(this);

    list.append("Play Video on Form", null);
    list.append("Play Video on Canvas", null);
    list.addCommand(exitCommand);
    list.setCommandListener(this);
  }

  public void startApp() {
    if (error)
      return;
    display.setCurrent(list); 
  }

  public void pauseApp() {
  }

  public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    try {
      if (player != null)
        player.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      error(e);
    }
  }

  public void commandAction(Command cmd, Displayable disp) {
    if (cmd == exitCommand) {
      destroyApp(true);
      notifyDestroyed();
    } else if (cmd == backCommand) { 
      try {
        if (player != null)
          player.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        error(e);
      }
      display.setCurrent(list);
      return;
    }
    try {
      loadPlayer();
      if (list.getSelectedIndex() == 0) { 
        GUIControl guiControl = (GUIControl) player.getControl("javax.microedition.media.control.GUIControl");

        if (guiControl == null)
          throw new Exception("No GUIControl!!");

        Item videoItem = (Item) guiControl.initDisplayMode(GUIControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE,     null);

        form.insert(0, videoItem);

        display.setCurrent(form);

        player.start();
      } else {
        VideoControl videoControl = (VideoControl) player.getControl("javax.microedition.media.control.VideoControl");
        if (videoControl == null)
          throw new Exception("No VideoControl!!");
        videoControl.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_DIRECT_VIDEO, canvas);
        videoControl.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
        videoControl.setVisible(true);
        display.setCurrent(canvas);
        player.start();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      error(e);
    }
  }

  private void loadPlayer() throws Exception {
    player = Manager.createPlayer(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/r.mp4"),"video/mpeg4");
    player.realize();
  }

  private void error(Exception e) {
    alert.setString(e.getMessage());
    alert.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
    display.setCurrent(alert);
    e.printStackTrace();
    error = true;
  }
}

class VideoCanvas extends Canvas {
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
  }
}
```

From http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0430__J2ME/DisplayVideo.htm